# Spring Batch - Custom Item Writer not Writing On file

Tags: java, spring-batch

at the End of the Batch File Created with the Name ReportDetail, But nothing is there in this file

```
public class ReportWriter implements ItemWriter<Record>,Closeable {

    private PrintWriter writer = null;

    public ReportWriter() {
        OutputStream out;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream("ReportDetail.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception e" + e);
            out = System.out;
        }
        try {
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(out);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(""+e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final List<? extends Record> items) throws Exception {
        for (Record item : items) {
            System.out.println("item.getCode()"); // this Prints the Code
            writer.println(item.getCode()); // Not Working
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a longer response for this, but as for your specific question, are you getting any exceptions, etc?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix your problem, but give it a try: use writer.flush(); after writer.println

Answer (score 2):

A couple things here:

1. Why not use the `FlatFileItemWriter`?  I don't see anything you're doing here that can't be done with it.
2. Don't use `Closable` for an `ItemWriter`.  Spring Batch has a lifecycle for opening and closing resources.  It's the `ItemStream` interface.  You can read more about it in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemStream.html
3. Your `PrintWriter` is not configured to flush automatically (it's false by default).  You need to either enable that (so that your writer flushes after each line) or explicitly call `writer.flush()` at the end of the write method.